# Unable to get ubuntu running normally on a Sager Clevo

Tags: networking, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I'm new to this so please be specific with me as to how to acquire more information if needed!

I've tried 3 major versions of Ubuntu, booting from USB with no luck.

I'm on a new Sager NP8955 (CLEVO P955ER).

Display adapters:
Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630
NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070 with Max-Q Design

Network adapters:
Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 and others

On Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 I have the same outcome. I can install the os but I can only start it in recovery mode and the wifi adapter's existence isn't acknowledged. I did some research and it seems like my wireless adapter is not supported on these versions of ubuntu.

On Ubuntu 18.04 I can not complete an installation because the os stops recognizing mouse clicks within 5-20 seconds of starting either the install process or the 'trial' mode. I got to the third or fourth screen of the install process once where it did recognize the existence of my wifi adapter.

My theory is that there is some sort of compatibility issue with my graphics card on all three major versions but I don't know what to do about that.

I would love any advice and will promptly reply to any information requests. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely stick with 18.04.  Did you hashcheck the downloaded iso?  Did you do a media-check after creating the install media?  Nvidia video usually requires a "nomodeset" on grub line starting with "linux" (type e to edit the grub commands, add the nomodeset at the "quiet splash" words.  If that boots, run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and then in the Software and Updates program (type in the launcher search to find that) under the additional drivers tab, select the Nvidia driver which says "tested" or the most current one.  Reboot and things should be better. I assume the wireless will just work under 18.04, if the install media is OK.

Comment: Thanks ubfan1, that did the trick! Like you said, I needed to use nomodeset then get the NVIDIA driver.